# Can't find correct JSON classes

Tags: c#, windows-8, json.net, deserialization

I have next JSON:

```
[
{
  "ApplicationRelations":[
     {
        "Application":null,
        "ApplicationSubcategory":null,
        "ApplicationCategory":{
           "categoryName":"Default Category",
           "id":4
        },
        "roleOrder":null,
        "categoryOrder":null,
        "subcategoryOrder":null,
        "applicationOrder":null,
        "id":6
     },
     {
        "Application":{
           "launchUrl":"link",
           "trainingUrl":"link",
           "installUrl":"link",
           "vpn":true,
           "overview":"text",
           "summary":"text",
           "id":12,
           "title":"Application"
        },
        "ApplicationSubcategory":{
           "subcategoryName":"Creation",
           "id":9
        },
        "ApplicationCategory":{
           "categoryName":"Default Category",
           "id":4
        },
        "roleOrder":15,
        "categoryOrder":25,
        "subcategoryOrder":35,
        "applicationOrder":45,
        "id":15
     }
  ],
  "roleName":"Role 02",
  "roleHeader":"Header of Role 02",
  "AnnouncementRelations":[

  ],
  "id":2
}
]
```

And here are my C# clases:

```
public class Applications
    {
        public List<SalesCentralApplicationRelation> salesCentralApplicationRelations { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public string RoleHeader { get; set; }
        public List<object> SalesCentralAnnouncementRelations { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
    public class SalesCentralApplicationRelation
    {
        public SalesCentralApplication salesCentralApplication { get; set; }
        public SalesCentralApplicationSubcategory salesCentralApplicationSubcategory { get; set; }
        public SalesCentralApplicationCategory salesCentralApplicationCategory { get; set; }
        public int roleOrder { get; set; }
        public int categoryOrder { get; set; }
        public int subcategoryOrder { get; set; }
        public int applicationOrder { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
    public class SalesCentralApplicationCategory
    {
        public string categoryName { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
    public class SalesCentralApplicationSubcategory
    {
        public string subcategoryName { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
    public class SalesCentralApplication
    {
        public string launchUrl { get; set; }
        public string trainingUrl { get; set; }
        public string installUrl { get; set; }
        public bool vpn { get; set; }
        public string overview { get; set; }
        public string summary { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }
```

And my deserialization:

```
var contents //JSON string above
Applications ApplicationsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Applications>(contents) as Applications;
```

And code fails with:

Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'App1.MainPage+Applications' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Path '', line 1, position 1.

**Checked my classes with json2csharp - all is fine... where is the problem?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your json is an array, not a single object. Try this:

```
var ApplicationsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Applications>>(contents);
```

Comment: I was thinking about it, but thought that there would be other error. But you are correct, thanks